# Handling multiple ui files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to the Qt framework and am trying to load another UI file when SubmitClicked. The file's name is Form.ui

```
//MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}
void MainWindow:: SubmitClicked()
{
   Form* f= new Form(this);
   f->show();
   f->raise();
   f->activateWindow();
}




//Form.cpp
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Form)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
delete ui;
}
```

This didn't work out! Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Explain "didn't work out". What did you expect? What happened?

Comment: It doesn't show? It doesn't compile? There is a crash? What happens?

Comment: Post the rest of your code and maybe someone can help.

Comment: Dear guys , thank you for your enthousiasme , i was expecting the From.ui file to to show once submit is clicked, the code didnt work out as it didnt do what i was expecting(it did compile) ... , once the submit button is clicked in the MainWindow nothing is done... , i wat the form.ui to appear once sumbmit is clicked in the main window...  thank you

Comment: Are you sure that SubmitClicked is getting called? Put a QMessageBox::information call in there to check.

Comment: Dear TonyK , thanks to the tip , it turned out the SubmitClicked is not called because i messed up something in the header file, anyhow i still have one more problem , the Form.ui is appearing but on top of the mainWindon , I just want to Form to appear, how can i close MainWindow ??? thank in advance

Comment: @karim you need to hookup a `slots:` for `QAction` and other events you want your window to handle. Instead of closing the `MainWindow` and causing the application to exit have you considered simply modifying it to do what you want? A child window can not exist without it's parent. You could add code to exit the application after they've finished with `Form` or your child window and close both at once or you could hide the `MainWindow` temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

The .ui file is simply where the code for GUI elements gets stored. This code is generated by the QtDesigner in most cases. It's similar to Visual Studio's .rc file and wizard generated GUI in function and form. This file will either be loaded at compile time which is the default or at runtime via the `QUiLoader`. If you want dynamically generated UI at runtime the latter is the option you need to look into starting with [QtUiTools](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtuitools.html)

On a side note the class `Form` does not exist in Qt so this is either a class you made or a typo. If you simply want to declare and show a window or dialog then derive from the appropriate base class and call `show()` or the appropriate method.

For example something simple like this where `MainWindow` is your own user defined class derived from `QMainWindow`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(application);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**Edit:**

Ah so `Form` is a `QWidget` class. Are you missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `Form` class? You also generally only call `setupUi` once for the main window of the application to load your resources and such where as user defined subclasses it's often easier to define gui objects for the class programmatically.

```
//Form.h
class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT // this is needed for the MOC aka qmake
public:
    Form(QWidget *parent);
    virtual ~Form();
private:
    QTextEdit m_text;
};

//Form.cpp
#include "form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setCentralWidget(&m_text);
}

Form::~Form()
{
}
```

It sounds almost like you're confusing your class object with your ui namespace files.

Comment: #include "form.h"
    #include "ui_form.h"

    Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
    {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    Form::~Form()
    {
    delete ui;
    }