# Controlling Multiple UI files in Qt framework

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

**Question asked twice:** see [Handling multiple ui files in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900147/handling-multiple-ui-files-in-qt)

I am new to Qt framwork , i have been given this simple task:

In the MainWindow , i have a submit button , once its clicked another total different window should appear

i thought of doing this by doing one extra UI file called From.ui file and to switch from MainWindow to Form once submit is clicked , this is my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setOrientation(MainWindow::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    mainWindow.showExpanded();

return app.exec();
}



//MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow:: SubmitClicked()
{
    Form* f= new Form(this);
       f->show();
       f->raise();
       f->activateWindow();
}




//Form.cpp
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

this code compiled perfectly , but its not doing as expected , once submit is clicked , nothing is done...

can you please tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: Why did you ask this question twice, karim? (The original is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900147/handling-multiple-ui-files-in-qt.) If you want to update the original question, just go there and click on `edit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SubmitClicked slot is not connected to clicked event of your button

Put a cout/printf at the top of your SubmitClicked method to make sure that it is called.

Comment: thanks for the tip , it turned out the SubmitClicked is not called because i messed up something in the header file, anyhow i still have one more problem , the Form.ui is appearing but on top of the mainWindon , I just want to Form to appear, how can i close MainWindow ??? thanks in advance

Comment: Try something like this : Form* f= new Form (); //Create form without parent.  f->show (); // Show the new form. this->close () ; //Close main form